# Flutter Firebase Database get List by IDs

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a basic Chat App with Flutter. I've set up a Firebase Realtime Database. There I have a node for groups and a node for posts. In groups there is a child "posts" where the post IDs are stored.

So far I can retrieve my groups using a Stream:

```
Stream<List<Group>> getGroupStream() {
final groupStream = _database.child('groups/').onValue;
final result = groupStream.map((event) {
  final groupMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      event.snapshot.value as Map);
  final groupList = groupMap.entries.map((element) {
    return Group.fromDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));
  }).toList();
  return groupList;
});
return result;}
```

I need the following function:

```
Stream<List<Post>> getPostStream(int group){...}
```

I need to provide a group ID, make data dabase query to get the post IDs from "groups/$groupId/posts/" and make another query to get only the posts that I need. I obviously don't want to get all posts and filter them afterwards.

Comment: What you're trying to do is known as a client-side join. While that *is* possible, the more idiomatic way to get this in a NoSQL database is to duplicate the data. I recommend reading [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and/or [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (the latter is for Firestore, but the logic applies equally to Realtime Database).